# SWIG: Compiler error when wrapping std::map<key, val *>

Tags: c++, swig

I found [this old issue](https://github.com/kkaempf/swig-issues/issues/50) and I have a similar problem for maps where the value is a pointer, not the key. I get this compiler error:

```
error: no member named 'type_name' in 'swig::traits<C>'
```

It happens both when I write my own typemap or if I use the SWIG "std_map.i" typemaps. What extra steps do I need to take to provide a type_name for pointed-to types?

---

Minimal working example:

```
%module stdmap;

%include "std_map.i"

%{
    class C
    {
        public:
             C() {};
    };
%}

class C
{
    public:
        C();
};

%template(mymap) std::map<int, C*>;
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIG is probably confused about the class pointer, since its wrappers use pointers anyway.  In any event, the SWIG docs say (bold mine):

> The library modules in this section provide access to parts of the standard C++ library including the STL. **SWIG support for the STL is an ongoing effort**. Support is quite comprehensive for some language modules but some of the lesser used modules do not have quite as much library code written.

I see two workarounds that work if you are free to change the implementation.  I used Python as the target language for testing:

1. Use `std::map<int,C>`:

```
%module stdmap

%include "std_map.i"

%inline %{

#include <memory>

class C
{
public:
    C() {};
};

%}

%template(mymap) std::map<int, C>;
```

Output (note `c` is a proxy object for a C* anyway):

```
>>> import stdmap
>>> c = stdmap.C()
>>> m = stdmap.mymap()
>>> m[1] = c
>>> c
<stdmap.C; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'C *' at 0x00000263B8DA5780> >
```

2. Use `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<C>>`:

```
%module stdmap

%include "std_map.i"
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"
%shared_ptr(C)

%inline %{

#include <memory>

class C
{
public:
    C() {};
};

%}

%template(mymap) std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<C> >;
```

Output (`c` is now a shared_ptr proxy):

```
>>> import stdmap
>>> c = stdmap.C()
>>> m = stdmap.mymap()
>>> m[1] = c
>>> c
<stdmap.C; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'std::shared_ptr< C > *' at 0x00000209C44D5060> >
```

Comment: I do need a pointer, because I'm need run-time polymorphism in the `map`. I can try your suggestion 2.